# Why don't Linux file permissions stop gzip overwriting the original file?

Tags: linux, permissions, gzip

I just noticed that gzip seems to be able to overwrite a file with its zipped counterpart despite the file permissions being set to read only.  I was under the impression that chmod 400 would prevent a file from being altered, and yet it seems that this is not the case.  Does overwriting a file not count as a "write"?  Or am I misunderstanding how permissions work?

For example, if I create a file full of zeros, remove write permissions, and then gzip it, the file is replaced by a smaller gzipped file.  I do not understand why the OS allows this.  This works with both SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2 and Linux Mint 20.2:

`

```
ng@bonobo:~/sandbox$ dd if=/dev/zero of=zeros bs=1 count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
100 bytes copied, 0.000693556 s, 144 kB/s
ng@bonobo:~/sandbox$ chmod 400 zeros 
ng@bonobo:~/sandbox$ ls -l
total 4
-r-------- 1 ng ng 100 Feb 10 23:58 zeros
ng@bonobo:~/sandbox$ gzip zeros 
ng@bonobo:~/sandbox$ ls -l
total 4
-r-------- 1 ng ng 30 Feb 10 23:58 zeros.gz
```

If I try to `rm` the file, I at least get a warning that it is write-protected, but I am allowed to proceed after typing y.  Similarly, I can edit a read-only file in `vim` and save it using ! to override the warning about it being read-only.

Does this mean that programs like `rm` and `vim` are making a system call to change the file permissions (which my account has authority to do), then changing the file, and then setting the permissions back to read-only?  And maybe `gzip` also does this but doesn't warn me first?

This is not really a big problem for me, but it makes me worry that I don't understand permissions and maybe files that I thought were somewhat safe from careless actions might not be so safe.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you.  I will keep this in mind in the future.  Since Stephen C was kind enough to answer, I am hesitant to delete it now.

Comment: It's up for deletion anyway and will be deleted eventually.

Comment: Read-only protects you from writing to the file, but it does not protect you from _deleting_ the file. gzip is deleting the file, not "overwriting" it. If you want to protect files from being deleted, then you need to make the _directory_ it is in read only.

Comment: Thanks, Mark Adler.  I think that was my misunderstanding.  I thought deletion counted as writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what `gzip` does and how it does it.

What it does is to compress the file *in place*.  How it does is to read the original file and then write a compressed version as a new file with a ".gzip" suffix.  If that succeeds, it delete the original.

The file system operations are:

- *open* and *read* the old file - that is permitted by the permissions on the file and parent directory
- *create* and *write* the new file - that is permitted by the permissions on the parent directory
- *delete* the old file - that is an operation on the parent directory, and it is permitted provided you have read and write permission for the directory.

OK ... why *doesn't* `gzip` explicitly check that the file is writeable before compressing it?  I don't *know*, but I probably would have implemented `gzip` like this too, considering that:

- it is convenient to be able to `gzip` a tree of files in place without jumping through hoops to deal with read-only files, and
- gzip compression is reversible and the actions of `gzip` are mostly (almost) reversible too.

Comment: I see.  Thank you very much fr your answer.